# \SetTracking from microtype is ineffective with mathdesign

Tags: microtype

I like the tracking but I wish to descrease the spacing a bit. But it does not work:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt]{article}    
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\usepackage[
protrusion=true,
tracking=true,
]{microtype}
\SetTracking{encoding={*}, family= mdbhc, shape=sc}{900}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}



\textsc{My text}
\end{document}
```

so

```
\SetTracking{encoding={*}, family= mdbhc, shape=sc}{900}
```

Has no effect on the spacing.

When I comment out the use of mathdesign in order to use the default font, the settracking is used and functions well.
I installed the microtype package yesterday, so it is the latest available.

Comment: The family name is `mdbch` (not `mdbhc`), and the shape should be `fsc` (not `sc`).

Comment: Yes fsc is the suitable value